# Правильне вживання назв професій та посад жіночого роду

Tags: граматика, фемінітиви

Протягом останніх років у засобах масової інформації все частіше я зустрічаю незвичне для повсякденного вживання застосування посад та професій по відношенню до жінок. Найяскравіші приклади це:
- прем'єрка;
- продавчиня;
- тощо.

На мою думку правильним вживанням є: "прем'єр міністр України (Марія Петренко)" замість "прем'єрка (Марія Петренко)". Моє питання полягає у тому, чи є це загальне правило вжитку або виняток?

Якщо це загальне правило, то чи правильно буде вживати:
- капітанка (для жінок у військовому званні "капітан");
- командирка (для жінки, що обіймає посаду командира);
- програмчиня (для жінки, що за фахом є програміст)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Подібні "жіночі" назви професій називаються **фемінітивами**. Наскільки я розумію, їх поява та поширення в українській мові пов'язані із вирівненням в правах чоловіків та жінок і часто сприймається, особливо особами жіночої статі, як вияв рівноправності чоловіків та жінок.

Водночас, у чинному законодавстві України немає фемінітивів. Тобто, ви не знайдете в офіційних документах формулювань на кшталт "*Заступник/Заступниця Міністра культури*", скрізь лише "*Заступник Міністра культури*", адже саме такою є офіційна назва посади, хоча її може обіймати особа будь-якої статі.

Щодо наведених вами прикладів, то, здається, так і буде правильно: *капітанка*, *командирка*. Але фемінітивом від слова *програміст* буде, напевно, все ж *програмістка*, а не *програмчиня*.

Також слід зауважити, що фемінітиви не є чимось унікальним для української мови. Вони поширені й в інших слов'янських мовах. Також, вони поширені, щонайменше, в іспанській мові.

Comment: Ще в німецькій дуже поширені фемінітиви, вони там від _усіх_ професій утворюються за допомогою суфікса _-in_, їх вживання обов’язкове. Кілька років тому вся Німеччина була просто в захваті, вперше в історії на посаду канцлера було обрано жінку, отже вперше ж таки в історії від слова _Kanzler_ було утворено фемінітив, _Kanzlerin_, відтоді це слово увійшло в словники й Меркель ніяк инакше не називають. До речи, Німецька хвиля українською теж завжди пише й говорить «канцлерка», [ось, наприклад](http://www.dw.com/uk/меркель-і-далі-виступатиме-проти-запровадження-межі-на-прийом-біженців/a-37429693)

Comment: [Тут](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2016/08/160816_ponomariv_blog99_ko) наводяться деякі зауваження до значень фемінітивів: "До таких слів як `філолог`, `соціолог`, `біолог` жіночих відповідників поки що немає. `Біологиня`, `філологиня`, `філософиня` – це розмовні назви _студенток_ біологічного, філологічного, філософського факультету."

Answer (score 10):

На мою думку, основна відмінність буде в тому чи це є офіційне чи неофіційне мовлення. Зокрема на рахунок першого існують такі правила:
В офіційно-діловому мовленні граматичний рід виконавців дій, назв осіб за професією, посадою, званням та ін. частіше, ніж в інших стилях, не відповідає статі . При виборі однієї з форм роду, в офіційно-діловому стилі , слід орієнтуватися на такі  правила:

1. Офіційними, основними  назвами посад, професій і звань є іменники чоловічого   роду:  директор,   дипломат,   ректор,  міністр,  нотаріус,  прокурор.  Ці  слова вживаються для позначення чоловіків та жінок  і підкреслюють не стать людини, а ї ї  службове  і  соціальне становище. Наприклад: Нараду провела декан (чол. р. ) факультету О.М.Пащенко;  Декан (чол.  р.)  факультету О.К.Гринчишин ознайомив викладачів з новими правилами вступу до університету.
2. Значна частина слів може утворювати паралельні форми чоловічого і жіночого роду:  журналіст –  журналістка,  студент – студентка,  аспірант – аспірантка, лікар – лікарка, лаборант – лаборантка, поет – поетеса,  дипломник – дипломниця.  Наведені  слова жіночого роду є цілком  літературними   відповідниками,   але   їм  надається   перевага   в художньому,  публіцистичному,  розмовному стилях.

Деякі  форми   слів   (ж.   р. )   із   суфіксами  –к(а),   -ш(а),   -их(а)  не відповідають нормам літературної мови: керівничка, фізичка, сторожиха,  бригадирша, професорша, дикторша.  Ці іменники використовуються у розмовно-просторічному   мовленні .   Обмежене   вживання   цих   слів зумовлене   також   тим,   що   ці   форми   означають   посаду   жінки   і найменування дружини за чоловіком. Все це створює двозначність, що не допускається в діловому стилі .

3. Відсутні відповідники жіночого роду у всіх складних назвах посад, звань: головний бухгалтер, віце-прем’єр, старший викладач, статист-дослідник,  змінний майстер тощо.
4. Текст   набуває   офіційного   характеру,   якщо   слова,   залежні   від найменування посади,  узгоджуються з цим найменуванням у формі чоловічого роду  і в тих випадках,  коли мова йде про жінок: Головний лікар дозволив…;  Змінний черговий  інженер завершив роботу…Проте,  якщо у документі  зазначено прізвище жінки,  яка займає названу посаду,   то   підпорядковані   дієслова   узгоджуються   з   прізвищем   і вживаються у формі  жіночого роду,  наприклад:  Головний бухгалтер Кравченко Галина Іванівна дозволила видачу грошей; Директор Іванова В.П.  оголосила подяку…Але висловлювання типу  «наша директор сказала», «наш головний бухгалтер дозволила» не відповідають нормам літературної  мови.
5. Вживання найменувань жіночого роду виправдано в тих випадках, для яких вказівка на стать є бажаною,  але не може бути виражена  іншими засобами.  Наприклад:  Успіхи українських гімнасток є закономірними.
6. Форми жіночого роду можуть використовуватись у випадках, коли назви   посад,   професій   стосуються   переважно   жінок,   або   чоловічі відповідники   мають   інші   позначення:  домогосподарка,   кастелянка (каштелянка) ,   манікюрниця,   доярка,   балерина,  закріпилася   пара медсестра  -  медбрат.
7. Помилковим є вживання в офіційно-ділових паперах найменування осіб за такими ознаками, як місце проживання, місце роботи або статус: заводчани, сільчани, городяни, кримчани, освітяни, циркачі . Ці слова є розмовними варіантами офіційних складних найменувань:  працівники заводу, жителі міста, працівники навчальних закладів, артисти цирку,  мешканці  Криму

Наведені у запитанні приклади радше винятки із правила, хоча, враховуючи гендерну політику і популярність цієї теми, не здивуюся, якщо вони стануть офіційно прийнятими нормами найближчим часом :)

Comment: Ця відповідь значно виграла б від додавання до неї посилань на поважні джерела.

Comment: Нажаль, ділова мова сформована за радянськими (російськими) правилами. У давніших текстах зустрічаємо "міністерка", "викладачка", ...щось на -иня не згадаю, але ж це звичайний спосіб формувати фемінітиви.

Comment: @SassaNF, богиня, берегиня, княгиня